# Probability, linearity of expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

[image: Question]
[image: answer1]
[image: answer2]

Hello, I would like to ask if part d) was solved right specifically the Var[Y] part.

Comment: Welcome to math exchange. Try to learn a bit of MathJax so that ask the questions without any links like that one.

Comment: How can I embed the photos so photos are shown without the link?

Comment: @drhab I showed my full answers in the photos above the question, what should I do more?

Comment: In general $\mathsf{Var}(a+bX)=b^2\mathsf{Var}(X)$. Does that answer your question? My former comment is a consequence of the fact that I just saw the $3$ links for only one link. Opening it I only saw some scratching (Answer2 I think). So I missed the other info, sorry.

Comment: @drhab in Var(a+bX)=b2Var(X) what about the (a) do i just remove it?

Comment: Yes. The variance of a random variable  $X$ will not be affected if a constant is added. $X$ and $a+X$ have the same variance.

Comment: @drhab so if Var[X]= -20.786, is Var[9-3X]= -187.07, also what about the mean how could I find it or is it just te E[Y]?
Thanks a lot tho

Comment: It cannot be that $\mathsf{Var}(X)$ takes a negative value, so something must be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a)

We must have $\sum_xp_X(x)=1$ where $x$ ranges over the values with positive probability.

This leads to $p_X(4.1)=0.1$

(c)

$\mathbb EX=\sum_xxp_X(x)=-9.1\times0.1-6.5\times0.2-3.4\times0.2+1.2\times0.4+4.1\times0.1=-2$

$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathbb EX^2-(\mathbb EX)^2=\sum_xx^2p_X(x)-(-2)^2=21.3-4=17.3$

or alternatively:

$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathbb E(X-\mathbb EX)^2=\sum_x(x+2)^2p_X(x)=17.3$

(d)

$\mathbb{E}Y=\mathbb{E}\left(9-3X\right)=9-3\mathbb{E}X=9-3\times\left(-2\right)=15$

$\mathsf{Var}Y=\mathsf{Var}\left(9-3X\right)=\left(-3\right)^{2}\mathsf{Var}X=9\times17.3=155.7$

$\mathbb EY^2=\mathsf{Var}Y+(\mathbb EY)^2=155.7+225=380.7$

---

Check yourself (and also check me).

Comment: yeah got the same answer mean is the E[Y] right? I mean in part d)

Comment: Yes, that is the same. Try to find what you did wrong (as I said: a variance is never negative). This is all I can do for you.

Comment: I already did its because when I was finding E[X^2] I didn't do it like this in the calculator (-9.1)^2 instead I wrote it -9.1^2 so I got a negative answer. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer is enough for you then you can accept it.